# Why would a 4 threads program run faster on a 1 core VM than on the same VM with 4 cores?

Tags: c, multithreading, time, parallel-processing, pthreads

- I use an i7 CPU with 4 cores (8 logical cores), a debian linux
- The VM is a debian linux too
- The program is compiled with gcc without special optimizations (default compilation settings)
- I loop 1000 times the program. It takes more than 2x longer when the VM has 4 cores. Why?

Note: The program I run is a C program and spawns 4 threads (pthread) and join on them after a little bit of computing. It does parallelism (not concurrency).

Comment: Could be false sharing, could be something else. Hard to know without seeing the source code.

Comment: Hum yeah, or maybe like if the L1 cache was long to transfer from a core to another one, such that the time to copy the memory in the other core is already longer than computing the task of the thread itself or something? This would sound right.

Comment: No one could possibly have a slightest idea about *your* program. You are giving close to zero useful information. We need the source code, full details about your VM setup, your measurements, and your measurement methods. Discussions about why programs in general may or may not work as expected are too broad.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share this code.

Comment: You can think of it as a simple map reduce.

Answer (score 0):

In the I7, all of the cores share the L3 cache.  It is possible to loose speed by adding cores if the extra line of execution causes more cache misses on the L3 cache.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems are embarrassingly parallel; some are "embarrassingly serial".  You may have hit on the latter, but without pushing your code, we can only guess.

BigLock solutions, for example trees, lists which can only be updated by locking the entire structure, do not benefit from multiple CPUs.   Worse, multiple CPUs might cause a bunch of thrashing around the locks which will gain nothing.